# Is it possible to save CSS and JS code in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm going to be using a **landing page service** that enables me to export the full **HTML** of the page, including the **CSS** and **JS** code.

However, I see when I copy/paste this code into my **TinyMCE** only the **HTML** portion gets saved.

Is there a way I can also have the **CSS** and **JS** code save properly in **TinyMCE** this way the landing page loads properly?

I created this **Plunker** link where you can see the code I'm trying to use.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/KSsMRCVG9WJ8B1HtM95h
```

In the **index.html** this is the original code, and in the **after-tinymce.html** code this is what TinyMCE ends up saving.

For the most part I see most of the **CSS** and **JS** gets saved properly and is the same as the original, however, if you look at **line 1425** and down in the **index.html** and compare it to the **after-tinymce.html** code this is the part that doesn't get saved properly which causes the page to not load properly on my website.

For example if you look at **line 1395** in the **after-tinymce.html** file you can see a chunk of the code is not saved for some reason.

```
<div class="column column-2 role-element leadstyle-container">&nbsp;</div>
```

In the **tinymce-helper.html** file you can see I have the **fullpage** plugin enabled on my website, so it should save all the code properly, but I'm not sure why the code towards the bottom of the page is not saving properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Never used TinyMCE. But as a workaround you can save the css and js within style and script tag in your HTML.

Comment: That's the issue TinyMCE strips the "style" and "script" tags when I save it in TinyMCE

Comment: I would make a TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle that shows what you are trying to load - this would allow people to see what configuration you are using with TinyMCE and what content you are trying to load.  An minimal, complete, verifiable example is always a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the code to plunker and added more details to my issue in my original post, so hopefully this will be more helpful. Ty.